# I'm Tring to get a user to chose with 2 buttons which site will be presented in iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, iframe

I'm Tring to get a user to chose with 2 buttons, which site will be presented in `iframe` tag.
`Option1.html` does work as default, but `Option1.html` & `Option2.html` do not work with user button.

**When Clicking the buttons, I Get the default browser error "Can’t reach this page".**

Please Take into account, that I a beginner with HTML and JS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Module choose</title>

</head>

<body>

    <p>Click to choose Module</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction1()">Option1</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction1() {
      document.getElementById("myframe").src = "Option1.htm";
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick="myFunction2()">Option2</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction2() {
      document.getElementById("myframe").src = "Option2.htm";
        }
    </script>


    <br><br>
    <iframe id="myframe" src="Option1.htm" width="1600" height="1600"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Option1.htm should be in the same directory where this html is there then it will work

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Still not working.

Comment: I wrote the same code you wrote it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first make a folder and put this code in that and make another html document named same as given in your code...

Or see this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Module choose</title>

</head>

<body>

    <p>Click to choose Module</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction1()">Option1</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction1() {
      document.getElementById("myframe").src = "index.html";
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick="myFunction2()">Option2</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction2() {
      document.getElementById("myframe").src = "index2.html";
        }
    </script>


    <br><br>
    <iframe id="myframe" src="Option1.htm" width="1600" height="1600"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This will be the main page...
And this will be inbdex.html. When user clicks option1 then this will be shown...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Seconds: <span id="time">0</span></div>
        <input type="button" id="startTimer" value="Start Timer" onclick="start();"><br/>
        <input type="button" id="stopTimer" value="Stop Timer"  onclick="stop();"><br/>
        <script>
            var timeElapsed = 0;
            var timerID = -1;
            function tick() {
                timeElapsed++
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeElapsed;
            }

            function start() {
                if(timerID == -1){
                    timerID = setInterval(tick, 1000);
                }
            }

            function stop() {
                if(timerID != -1){
                    clearInterval(timerID)
                    timerID = -1
                }
            }

            function reset() {
                stop();
                timeElapsed = -1;
                tick()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the below thing will be index2.html. So when user clicks option2 then this will be shown!

```
<html>
this is other page
</html>
```

Comment: Did the Trick. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome & HAPPY CODING